# Decision tree and relationship between test and train results over time

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, cart

**My goal** is to predict the number of policies in 5 years. Therefore, I train a decision tree that predicts the termination probability for each contract in a given year.

Then, I use a test data set and compute the termination probabilities for the first year for each contract. After that, I increment variables like age by one, or increment grouped variables by one and reevaluate the classes. Variables that don't change over time remain the same. Next, I calculate the probabilities for the second year. I repeat that procedure until I have probabilities for 5 years for each contract. By doing that, I assume time-invariance. I use the 5 probabilities to get a final termination probability for each contract and add those up to get the final number of contracts.

Let's say 80 % of the portfolio remains after 5 years. I would assume that the yearly termination is approximately 20 % / 5 years = 4 % per year. If I calculate the weighted average of the terminal nodes after training, i.e., by looking at the plot of the tree after training, I get, say, 2 %. Assuming a lapse rate of 2 % or 4 % per year makes a big difference to me after 5 years.

**My question** is, can I use the weighted average on the training set as an indicator for the viability of my results with the test set? Whether yes or no, why?